# Solving an equation iteratively

Tags: python, iteration, equation, brute-force

I would like to know how can I optimize a problem with the equation below:

```
R=A/B*C/D
```

Where R is the input value and the `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are one value from a list of integers e.g. `[20,21,22,23,24,24,25,25,26,28,28,28,36,36,37,38,38,39,40,40,41,42,42,43]`

The goal is to find the values of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` that are most close of `R`.

I'm using Cython to try to run things faster but is still takes some minutes to solve.

I'm not asking for the solution, just some help pointing me to the right direction with the right words.

EDIT: To answer some questions

- I'm brute forcing because I don't know any other way of doing this, I accept suggestions.
- There are intentionally duplicates in the list, one possible solution is A=21, B=38, C=28, D=28.
- The list could be as long as 150 elements

  Here is what I have at the moment with Cython:

  ```
  def __init__ (self, **kwargs) :
      self._arr           = (20,20,21,22,24,25,27,30,34,35,36,38,40,44,45,46,46,47,48,50,51,52,54,55,56,58,60,62,65,68,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,120,127) 
      self._desiredNumber = kwargs.get('desiredNumber', None)


  def doesFit(self, *set):
      # check values of A, B, C and D agains harcodded limits, 
      # if conditions met return true, else return false
      return true

  def solver(self, float desiredError = 0.00001):
      cdef float computedNumber, computedError
      computedNumber = 0
      computedError = 0

      cdef int arrSize, a, b, c, d
      a = 0
      b = 0
      c = 0
      d = 0
      arrSize = len (self._arr)

      cdef vector[float] arr = self._arr

      result = []

      for a from 0 <= a < arrSize:
          for b from 0 <= b < arrSize:
              for c from 0 <= c < arrSize:
                  for d from 0 <= d < arrSize:
                      computedNumber=arr[a]/arr[b]*arr[c]/arr[d]
                      computedError = fabs (self._desiredNumber - computedNumber)
                      if computedError<=desiredError and (a!=b and a!=c and a!=d and b!=c and b!=d and c!=d):
                          if self.doesFit(arr[a], arr[b], arr[c], arr[d]):
                              result.append(dict (A=arr[a], B=arr[b], C=arr[c], D=arr[d], desiredError=computedError, computedNumber=computedNumber))

      # remove results with duplicated values of A, B, C and D. 
      # A/B*C/D is the same as C/D*A/B, etc
      keyfunc = lambda d: (d['A'], d['B'], d['C'], d['D'])
      giter = groupby(sorted(result, key=keyfunc), keyfunc)
      result = [next(g[1]) for g in giter]

      # sort results by desiredError
      result = sorted(result, key=itemgetter('desiredError'))

      # returns just the 12 best results
      if len(result) > 12:    
          result = result[0:12]    

      return result
  ```

Comment: Several minutes in Cython? I'm pretty sure `solver` in MS Excel would converge quickly on this. I think even pre-cython python code would help here to see the issue. Are you brute-forcing?

Comment: How big is that list?

Comment: The list you posted has several duplicates. You might want to use, say, `list(sorted(set(values)))` to fix that first (if for no other reason, to minimize the space you have to brute-force ;) )

Comment: How does your current solution looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking for, specifically, is a brute force function.  As suggested in the comments, I did enforce a unique array to speed up the algorithm.

```
arr = [20,21,22,23,24,24,25,25,26,28,28,28,36,36,37,38,38,39,40,40,41,42,42,43]

def iterSolvePython(arr, desiredNumber):
    arr = list(sorted(set(arr)))
    best = {'a':arr[0],'b':arr[0],'c':arr[0],'d':arr[0], 'r': 1}
    for a in arr:
        for b in arr:
            for c in arr:
                for d in arr:
                    r = float(a)/b*c/d
                    if abs(desiredNumber-r) < abs(desiredNumber-best['r']):
                        best = {
                            'a':a,
                            'b':b,
                            'c':c,
                            'd':d,
                            'r':r
                        }
    return best

print(iterSolvePython(arr, 25))
```

Comment: I did cast a as a float, so we can now get float values, BUT, think about it... Our max value is 43/21*43/21 which is approximately 4.  The max for this data set **is** (aprox.) 4.

Comment: 43/20*22/21 is non-debatably less than 43/21*43/21